# Копирование автора и названия композиции из меню

Tags: c#, uwp

Решил написать для собственных нужд приложение, которое берет название трека и автора из меню громкости(простите, но не знаю, как оно называется, скрин ниже) и переводит его в .txt файл. Есть ли какие-либо инструменты Win10(возможно код), которые позволяют посмотреть, какая композиция играет? Если такие инструменты есть, то возникает еще один вопрос, как можно реализовать обновление .txt файла при обновлении композиции?(или же можно создать таймер, который каждую секунду будет проверять, сменилась ли композиция?). Спасибо.[image: Меню изменения громкости Windows10 с названием композиции]

Comment: потрудитесь пояснить, что это за квадратики-кружочки у вас на скрине и как это связано вообще с вопросом? Что за меню громкости? Системный микшер не показывает треки, а если у вас какая то прогрмма, с которой вы хотиет работать, то надо об этом явно писать в впросе.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Данный трек воспроизводился из приложения Музыка Groove(логотип - это " квадратики-кружочки у вас на скрине "). Суть не в этом, ведь помимо вышеперечисленного приложения, в данное меню, название композиции/имя автора, могут передавать и другие приложения для воспроизведения мультимедиа и даже сайты, такие как YouTube и VK. Поэтому вопрос заключался именно в том, как из этого меню взять название композиции и автора/исполнителя.

Comment: это меню windows 10? Разве не каждое прилоежние должно само свое меню рисовать? Например, если вы запустите 2-3 приложения сразу, там будет несколько меню одновременно? Вам надо извлекать данные из файлов с музыкой или из приложений?

Comment: Я уточнил, что  не знаю, как точно это называется. Но по сути, это меню, где дается возможности - прибавить/убавить громкость, а также включить/остановить трек и т.п. Оно рисуется именно Windows 10, а не отдельно каждым приложением, как я понял, но возможно ошибаюсь. Если запустить 2-3 приложения с воспроизведением, то там будет несколько меню. Мне нужно, чтобы человек, запустил любой трек, в любом источнике, смог вывести его название в .txt файл.

Comment: @tym32167 как я понял, он просто хочет писать логи того, что у него играло. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207316/12888024

Comment: @aepot ну то есть автору нужен софт, который будет все время висеть в памяти (как приложение или сервис) и по событиям `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager` будет смотреть, что происходит и писать треки в файлик.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @tym32167, Вы все верно подумали. В основном, это понадобится не рядовым пользователям, а людям которые проводят прямые эфиры. Я не нашел простых и бесплатных приложений, которые могут вышеперечисленное.

Comment: Вызывает исключение System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе". Я так понимаю нужны админ.права? Если да, то как их выдать на UWP?

Comment: Это меню громкости как-то криво работает (во всяком случае, у меня). Например, смотрел я ютуб в браузере, поставил на паузу. Запустил медиапроигрыватель. А в этом меню по-прежнему указан ютуб.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если вы запустили второй медиапроигрыватель и не закрыли второй, то рядом с иконкой воспроизведения появится стрелочка вправо ">" - нажмите на нее и тогда вы сможете управлять другим проигрывателем.